# Checking Overfitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation, training-data

I want to be sure that my model is not overfitting. I checked the overfitting using cross validation. Results of all folds are close.But at the same time I checked the train and test predictions. Test size is 0.25. And train and test predictions are so different. It shows that my model is overfitting. Which result should I believe? Cross validation or test/train prediction.Is my model overfitting?

Note:I used python. Sklearn for cross validation, train test split and modelling

Comment: If I'm reading you, 75% of the data was used to train your model and 25% was used to test it? Then you performed a cross-validation procedure? How many observation do you have in your dataset, and how many folds did you use for cross-validation?

Comment: My data observation is 28000 row. Test size is 0.25. Train prediction is 0.99. Test prediction is 0.74. Cross validation is 10 fold. Each fold accuracy is between 0.70 and 0.77.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but first of all i would recomend you to trust in cross-validation results. 
Cross valitation divides the data in N splits and uses N-1 to train and 1 for test each time so its results shows more realistic results.
I would recommend you also o shuffle the data and calculate the confidence interval of your evaluation.

The 95% confidence interval can be calculated as:

```py
aux = 1.96 * sqrt((evaluation*(1-evaluation))/num_test_samples)
```

Having the cross validations evaluation with its corresponding confidence interval, remember that you can get the train evaluation also in cross_validate() method if i'm not wrong.

With theese three things you can see how much change the train evaluation and the test evaluation.
If your train evaluation is very bigger to your test evaluation, you probably have overfitting.

When your train results are very big in comparison to your test evaluation and the train accuracy tends to 100% you know that your model is not generalizing well.
Specifically in neural networks, is easy to see with the epoch pass.

Answer (score 0):

From the accuracies you've given, both methods say you have overfitting. Cross validation is just a more accurate way to test how well the model generalises, so don't compare folds, compare the average cross validation accuracy with the training accuracy, since these are very different you have overfitting